# Will ignoring to call openssl EVP_cleanup result in serious flaws or memory leaks?

Tags: c++, openssl, evp-cipher

I have an odd situation in my application. I am using the EVP methods in OpenSSL to compute digests and perform encryption. At the end of it, I am performing an **EVP_cleanup()** in the destructor of my CryptoProvider class (the main gateway to my application). It unloads all the algorithms etc. from the OpenSSL state.

However, this makes it impossible for seamless usage of OpenSSL outside my application, if the client is using it for something else. It cleans up their work as well.

Now, I am left with these choices:

- Ignore EVP_cleanup(). Will this result in leaks or other consequences?
- Set up a static API for cleanup in my application, that the client must call towards the end of their lifetime, which is much after the lifetime of my application.
- Just trust the client to call EVP_cleanup at the end of its lifetime.

What do you think you would do here?

Comment: Reference count the use of your CryptoProvider class. Only call `EVP_cleanup()` when the reference count drops to 0.

Comment: Actually I call EVP_cleanup() after all my usage is done. But there are other pieces of the client application which use OpenSSL, not through my CryptoProvider or my library. I have no control on this usage. So, I will have to probably not do EVP_cleanup at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I had this question this morning and came across this thread... It would have saved me time if I would have found the following response:

The EVP_cleanup() function was deprecated in OpenSSL versions 1.0.2h and 1.1.0.

See thier [change-log](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html) for full details.

Excerpt:

"Make various cleanup routines no-ops and mark them as deprecated. Most global cleanup functions are no longer required because they are handled via auto-deinit (see OPENSSL_init_crypto and OPENSSL_init_ssl man pages). Explicitly de-initing can cause problems (e.g. where a library that uses OpenSSL de-inits, but an application is still using it). The affected functions are CONF_modules_free(), ENGINE_cleanup(), OBJ_cleanup(), EVP_cleanup(), BIO_sock_cleanup(), CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data(), RAND_cleanup(), SSL_COMP_free_compression_methods(), ERR_free_strings() and COMP_zlib_cleanup()."

Comment: Found out the hard way that EVP_cleanup() will cause Apache web server to fail authentication... apparently calling it on a system where Apache is running causes Apache to lose its TLS certificate.